# Windows phone 8 emulator does not receive pushes.

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have Windows Phone 8 emulator running and a sample app is registering and I receive the URI but when I try to send a notification, I'm not receiving in the emulator. I used to be able to use the sample app with WP7 emulator and it was working and I'm able to access internet on the WP8 but not the notification. Any pointers to fix this will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I saw happening:

1- If I didn't open the app after receiving multiple notification it looks like the OS will not show notification anymore.

2- if you try to send too many notifications.

3- If the app is open the notification will not show as a toast.

4- Sometime I had to open the browser and go to website to force the device to connect to the internet, probably because the phone was on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty open question, since there might be multiple problems, but start with this (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637317%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_PushNots)):

> The push client service on Windows Phone Emulator must be ready before
>   you can use push notification APIs. Push client service on the
>   emulator takes two minutes to activate after you start the emulator,
>   starting from when the Start screen first appears.

Comment: Thank, I saw this but it was not an issue since I re-installed after it was ready. I did also try to send API request from the phone and it was working fine the only thing that was not working was the push notification service.